# Adding a UISegmentedControl under NavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uitableview

I’m adding a UISegmentedControl right under the NavigationBar in a UITableViewController. This is the code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    UIView *segmentView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [segmentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    segmentView.alpha = 0.95;
    self.tabSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Favourites", @"All", nil]];
    self.tabSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, self.navigationBar.frame.size.width - 40, 30);
    [self.tabSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(tabChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [segmentView addSubview:self.tabSegmentedControl];
    [self.navigationBar addSubview:segmentView];
    [self.tabSegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
}
```

The view and the SegmentedControl appear on the screen well, but they are not clickable. The selector doesn’t get executed when tapped on the SegmentControl; it doesn’t even switch tabs! In fact, the stuff that is underneath the `segmentView` (items in the TableView) get clicked when you tap on it. I have tried but failed to understand why this is happening! Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Why are you adding segmentView as a subview of the navigation bar? I think it appears in the right place, overall, because you've set itf frame correctly. But not sure it should be a subview of the navigation bar...

Comment: I want the whole thing to be a part of the navigation bar. I tried adding it as a subview of self.view, but that moves the whole segmentView along with the table. I want it not to move.

Comment: So you want the segmented control to be part of the navigation bar, but below the title/buttons of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a view below the bounds of its super view. You may see the view however you cannot click it because it is out of bounds. If you set the property of the navigation bar `clipsToBounds` to `YES` you should see that the view disappears. What you need to do is add the segment controller to the table view. Here is an example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    [self.view addSubview: self.segmentView]; // need to keep a pointer to segmentView
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInset(self.segmentView.frame.size.height, 0,0,0);
}

-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*) scrollView{
    CGRect rect = self.segmentView.frame;
    rect.origin = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    self.segmentView.frame = rect;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Could you please explain what the `scrollViewDidScroll` method does here?

Comment: When you add subviews to the view of the tableview controller you are actually adding them to the tableview. If you don't implement that function then your segment view would scroll off the page. Implementing that view ensures that it stays at the top of the page.